# I have made a Roulette Simulator but it won't add or subtract from my money, why?

Tags: python-2.7, roulette-wheel-selection

When you lose it won't subtract money and when you win it doesn't add money, why? Also if there is a simplier way to define role() please let me know. Python 2.7 here is the code.

```
`from random import randint #import random intergers
b="Your color is Black." #Makes easier to define black
r="Your color is Red." #Makes easier to define red
print "Welcome to Roulette Simulator 2.0! This is made for people the age of 21+."
print "This is not avaliable for distribution. Please do not distribute."
print "By using this you undestand this is not real money."
print "Made by: Jacob Lloyd"
user_color_number = 0
number = 0
bet=0
monei = raw_input("How much money do you wish to start with? :>")
money = int(monei)
number_color=0
def role(): #define what a role() is
    global number
    number = (randint(0,36))
    print number
    if number == 28: #if then "==' means equal to
        print b
    if number == 26:
        print b
    if number == 11:
        print b
    if number == 20:
        print b
    if number == 17:
        print b
    if number == 22:
        print b
    if number == 15:
        print b
    if number == 24:
        print b
    if number == 13:
        print b
    if number == 0:
        print ("Your color is Green.") #If number on roulette = zero make it green
    if number == 10:
        print b
    if number == 29:
        print b
    if number == 8:
        print b
    if number == 31:
        print b
    if number == 6:
        print b
    if number == 33:
        print b
    if number == 4:
        print b
    if number == 35:
        print b
    if number == 2:
        print b
    if number == 9: #Starting red here
        print r
    if number == 30:
        print r
    if number == 7:
        print r
    if number == 32:
        print r
    if number == 5:
        print r
    if number == 34:
        print r
    if number == 3:
        print r
    if number == 36:
        print r
    if number == 1:
        print r
    if number == 27:
        print r
    if number == 25:
        print r
    if number == 12:
        print r
    if number == 19:
        print r
    if number == 18:
        print r
    if number == 21:
        print r
    if number == 16:
        print r
    if number == 23:
        print r
    if number == 14:
        print r
    continu=raw_input("Press enter to continue.")
    color_numbers()
def bets(): #how much to bet
    global bet
    global money
    print "You have $", money
    minimum=25
    if money == 0:
        goodbye()
    bet_amount = raw_input("How much would you like to bet? :> $")
    if bet_amount is int:
        bet = int(bet_amount)
    if bet>>money: #if bet is more than money go to bet_too_much
        bet_too_much()
    color()
def not_a_bet():
    print "Thats not a number. Please try again."
    bets()
def bet_too_little():
    print "Your bet is below minimum bets! The minimum bet is $26. Please try again."
    bets()
def goodbye():
    print"You are out of money. Press enter to exit!."
def bet_too_much(): #what happens if bet is too much
    print "Your bet is too much. Please try again."
    bets()
def win():
    global bet
    global money
    print "You won!"
    money = money ++ bet
    play()
def lose():
    global bet
    global money
    print "You lost, but don't give up yet!"
    drop_money=1
    if drop_money==0:
        money=money -- bet #subtract bet from money
    play()
def color():
    global user_color_number
    user_color=raw_input("Which color would you like to pick? Black or Red? :> ")
    if user_color == "Black":
        global user_color_number
        print "You have bet on Black! "
        user_color_number=1
        role()
    if user_color == "Red":
        global user_number_color
        print "You have bet on Red!"
        user_color_number=2
        role()
def win_or_lose():
    global user_color_number
    global number_color
    if number_color == user_color_number:
        win()
    if number_color != user_color_number:
        lose()
def color_numbers():
    global number_color
    global number
    if number == 28: #if then "==' means equal to
        number_color=1
    if number == 26:
        number_color=1
    if number == 11:
        number_color=1
    if number == 20:
        number_color=1
    if number == 17:
        number_color=1
    if number == 22:
        number_color=1
    if number == 15:
        number_color=1
    if number == 24:
        number_color=1
    if number == 13:
        number_color=1
    if number == 0:
        number_color=0
    if number == 10:
        number_color=1
    if number == 29:
        number_color=1
    if number == 8:
        number_color=1
    if number == 31:
        number_color=1
    if number == 6:
        number_color=1
    if number == 33:
        number_color=1
    if number == 4:
        number_color=1
    if number == 35:
        number_color=1
    if number == 2:
        number_color=1
    if number == 9: #Starting red here so number_color shall equal 2
        number_color=2
    if number == 30:
        number_color=2
    if number == 7:
        number_color=2
    if number == 32:
        number_color=2
    if number == 5:
        number_color=2
    if number == 34:
        number_color=2
    if number == 3:
        number_color=2
    if number == 36:
        number_color=2
    if number == 1:
        number_color=2
    if number == 27:
        number_color=2
    if number == 25:
        number_color=2
    if number == 12:
        number_color=2
    if number == 19:
        number_color=2
    if number == 18:
        number_color=2
    if number == 21:
        number_color=2
    if number == 16:
        number_color=2
    if number == 23:
        number_color=2
    if number == 14:
        number_color=2
    win_or_lose()

def play():
    while money>=1: #It will run code ( role() ) back to back f statement = true
         bets()
play()
```

`https://pastebin.com/tNifKRKS

(I can't find how to format it so it's all there :))

Comment: instead of ++ and -- just use + and -

Comment: For sure there many simplier ways to define the function `role`. Instead of using so many if-else statements, you could use only one, e.g. doing `if number in [28, 26, ..., etc ]:print b`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
drop_money=1
if drop_money==0:
    money=money -- bet #subtract bet from money
```

Your code sets `drop_money` to `1` every time. But it only does the "subtraction" when `drop_money` is zero, which is never.

I put *subtraction* in scare quotes for a reason: please don't do this:

```
money=money -- bet #subtract bet from money
```

This does the opposite of what you want, because it is interpreted as

```
money = money - (- bet)
```

which is the same as

```
money = money + bet
```

Instead, choose one of these:

```
    money = money - bet 
    money -= bet
```

There is a similar though less visible problem with

```
money = money ++ bet
```

That is the same as

```
money = money + (+bet)
```